# UIViewController not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I have a log in function that goes to parse and validates log in.  Then when it returns I present a different view with the following code.

```
 var storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
 var vc: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileView") as UIViewController
 println("got here");
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
 println("got here too");
```

got here prints to the console got here too does not, the view did load function for ProfileView never gets called.  There are no errors in the log and no warnings during compilation. the application does not crash I can keep trying to log in but it will never load the next view or print the second message.

The code did work but then I altered the ProfileView a little bit and it stops. I have reverted the view and its still broken, I have cleaned and rebuilt.  Is there anything I should be looking for specifically?

Upon request here are the top lines of ProfileView.

```
class ProfileView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
var profilePic: PFObject!
var imageArray: [PFObject]!
```

when I instantiate those objects with an init method the init method will run and I can break point it but the view will not load cause I never hit the break point on the first line of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Im confused does it crash or does it not?

Comment: I should have specified the code continues to run I can try and log in again and again and each time the got here message will appear in the log but the view will not present and the got here too message will not fire

Comment: That sounds very weird...

Comment: yes i've been working on it for 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Storyboard Identifier is not set to `ProfileView` in Interface Builder. Also, in the event you want to set Profile View controller specific properties, you shouldn't cast as `UIViewController` instead use the class of your Profile View Controller

It might also help to have a `UIStoryboard` extension that loads your view controllers via helper methods e.g.

```
extension UIStoryboard {

  class func loadProfileViewController() -> ProfileViewController {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      return storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileView") as! ProfileViewController
  }

}
```

This way you can write `let profileVC = UIStoryboard.loadProfileViewController()`

Comment: I have the storyboard ID.  That will throw an error btw if you don't have it set and you reference it.  When I set up an init method inside of ProfileViewController it did infact instantiate the profileView it just wouldn't show it.

Comment: Are you using initWithCoder:?

Comment: I don't think so because I don't know what that is. the top few lines of ProfileView.swift have been added to the bottom of my original message